# How to display specific nodes in an EVA based on common taxonomy

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms, entities

I am trying to display nodes in an EVA, attached to a node type that shares taxonomy.  The EVA passes the node ID to the EVA, so I have a contextual filter, but am having trouble figuring out how to filter the EVA nodes by their shared taxonomy values.  It seems like I need to create a relationship in some way, but that doesn't work.

How can I filter out the nodes in my EVA that share the same taxonomy terms of the main attached node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Construct your eva field view as follows: view of nodes filtered by your content type.

**Relationships:**

a. Content: terms (field_YOUR_TERM_FIELD). Require this relationship.

b. Taxonomy term: Content with term. Set the Relationship to relationship 'a'. Require this relationship.

**Contextual filters:**

a. Content: Nid. Set the relationship to relationship 'b'.

b. Content: Nid. NO relationship. In more tick exclude.

**Arguments (in Entity content section):**

Select 'Use tokens from the entity the view is attached to'. Then add this as your arguments: `[node:nid]/[node:nid]`

**In OTHER section of views**: click on query settings, and select 'Distinct'.

The reason two almost identical contextual filters are used is as follows: the first one ties up the relationships that you brought in, the second one excludes the current node from the result set.

Comment: I tried this way not with a node the eva is attached to but with a field collection. To get the field_YOUR_TERM_FIELD I needed an additional relationship (AA:)Entity Reference: Referencing entity (required). Then I used the relationship Field collection item: field_MY_TERM_FIELD, related to AA. In context filters I replaced Content: NID with Field collection item: Field collection item ID. But both filters only WITH relationship to B. Not without or another relationship is possible. There is completely no output. Is there a solution?

Comment: This solution is BANG ON. It worked for me after I was about to bang my head on the wall. +1 for J. Reynolds.

Answer (score 4):

From the [EVA project page](http://drupal.org/project/eva):

> In addition, the unique ID of the entity the view is attached to -- as well as any tokens generated from that entity -- can be passed in as arguments to the view.

Pass the Taxonomy terms as arguments to the view attachment. You may then add a `contextual filter` to the view attachment which can make use of these arguments and  require the arguments be of terms within the appropriate vocabulary.